# Installing a file to the GAC through a Sharepoint 2007 WSP package

Tags: deployment, solution-package

I'm creating a WSP package in Visual Studio 2010 to deploy my feature to the Sharepoint 2007 environment on a Windows 2003 Server box.  Currently, the xml file that references the assembly containing the code I have written is referenced from the GAC.  What I'd like to do is make it so this WSP file will add the dll to the assembly automatically and then reference it so the feature can be properly installed.  Is this possible? If so, how is this done?

I have my ListManifest.xml file as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
<Receivers ListTemplateId="101">
    <Receiver>
        <Name>AddedEventHandler</Name>
        <Type>ItemAdded</Type>
        <SequenceNumber>10000</SequenceNumber>
        <Assembly DeploymentTarget="GlobalAssemblyCache" Location="SPEventHandler.dll"/>
        <Class>SPEventHandler.ItemAddedHandler</Class>
        <Data></Data>
        <Filter></Filter>
    </Receiver>
</Receivers>
```

As you can see, it references the SPEventHandler assembly in the GAC, but I'd like the program to have my DLL included in the assembly, add it to the GAC and reference it.

Thanks for your help in advance.

My DDF file:

```
.OPTION Explicit ; Generate errors
.Set DiskDirectory1="..\bin"
.Set CabinetNameTemplate="ChangeContentType.wsp"

manifest.xml
.Set DestinationDir="List\ListTemplates"
List\ListTemplates\ListManifest.xml ; specify cab file name
.Set DestinationDir="List\Messages"
List\Messages\schema.xml
.Set DestinationDir="List"
List\Feature.xml
..\bin\SPEventHandler.dll SPEventHandler.dll
```

manifest.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Solution xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/"
   SolutionId="F9850E13-81B6-47E1-BBC6-42AC70A903C3" >
   <FeatureManifests>
       <FeatureManifest Location="List\Feature.xml"/>
   </FeatureManifests>
</Solution>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are packaging your wsp manually, then you need to include your dll in your DDF file, e.g.

```
bin\Debug\MyFile.dll MyFile.dll
```

and you include the assembly in the solution manifest, e.g.

```
<Assemblies>
  <Assembly DeploymentTarget="GlobalAssemblyCache" Location="MyFile.dll" />
</Assemblies>
```

Here is an [MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb466225%28office.12%29.aspx)

If you do not want to do this manually, you can take a look at [WSPBuilder](http://wspbuilder.codeplex.com/).

Comment: I added my ddf file to the original question text.  Do I just add the line for the DLL at the bottom or do I need to do a .Set DestinationDir="" ?

Comment: Just add the line to the bottom of your DDF.

Comment: Cool.  Also, can I use the following syntax to access a file in a different folder: ..\..\SPEventHandler\bin\Debug\SPEventHandler.dll SPEventHandler.dll ?

Comment: The path should be to the bin folder in your project. Make sure that the dll is in that folder.

Comment: Hi again - I've updated my ListManifest.xml file (as visible in my original question text).  When I go to run the deployment command, however (stsadm -o addsolution -filename ChangeContentType.wsp), I get the following error: "The 'DeploymentTarget' attribute is not declared." Any thoughts/suggestions?
Also, here is the line that I added to my DDF file: ..\bin\SPEventHandler.dll SPEventHandler.dll

Comment: Do I need to change the location of my file to : <Assembly DeploymentTarget="GlobalAssemblyCache" Location="..\..\..\bin\SPEventHandler.dll"/> ? Sorry for all the questions - I have to reach out to my manager every time I try to deploy so I'm trying to limit the number of times I do.

Comment: Do I need to add an entry to my manifest.xml? (see edited question for code)

Comment: You can verify that the dll is in your wsp by renaming it to .cab and extracting the files. As far as the Assembly node, that belongs in the manifest.xml file and should not have a path in it. Take a look at the MSDN instructions for where to put that node.